# one row gallery with inline-block li, all of the layout depending on % height

Tags: html, css

I have a one row gallery, which is responsive in height. Images are in a list, where the li's are set to display:inline-block and are scaled to the height of the container of the ul.
On hover an overlay with some caption is displayed.

<strike>This works, except for one very annoying detail:</strike>
When adjusting the browser zoom level (Strg + Mousewheel) or changing the height of the browser window causes that the images move horizontally, overlapping or increasing the space between them.

The imgs are not given any Width. Their height is 100%, the height of all surrounding containers up to body & html is 100%. Except for one which has a height of 60% and therefore defining the height of the imgs. I expected that this will also define the width of the image, which I was hoping would define the width of the surrounding containers.
--> can this be done? Or do I need to set an actual width using JS?

When setting the li's to inline, this behaviour can be prevented, but then I can't bring the overlay to overlay the entire image. They only overlay an area on the bottom of the image, with one line-height.

I would prefer to not float the li's if possible..

to make things easier to understand and toy around with, here a simplified version of the code and a jsfiddle:

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7Q83j/12/

simplified code:

html:

```
<div id="mainContent">
    <div id='hlGalleryWrapper'>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <img id='img1' alt='' src='http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png'/>
                <div class='img-overlay'>
                   someCaption
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#mainContent {
    padding-left:150px;
    height:60%;
}

#hlGalleryWrapper {
    white-space: nowrap;
    height:100%;
}
#hlGalleryWrapper ul,
#hlGalleryWrapper ul li img {
    height:100%;
}

#hlGalleryWrapper ul li {
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    height:100%;
}

#hlGalleryWrapper ul li .img-overlay {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSFiddle logo has a size of 136 x 23 pixels and the `li` element is exactly 136 pixels wide. So it seems that the `li` considers the original size, but doesn't allow for the increase in width, when the logo is zoomed to adapt for the `height: 100%`.

Apparently, the solution would be to use an image, which has an appropriate size and doesn't need to zoom.

Comment: Interesting and thanks for the answer!! Unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem on the site the fiddle is based on. The site is so far only local. It doesn't contain any iframes. I will try to reproduce the error for the fiddle.

Comment: one my site I have another wrapper, with overflow:hidden arround everything. This breaks the fiddle, surprisingly the images are displayed wrong even without zooming. Removing this wrapper doesn't fix the site though. Actually it seems that things are just displayed right by pure chance, as resizing the browser window also destroys the layout (on the site).
broken fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Q83j/9/show/